# Is it possible to resolve domain names to an IP address with PHP?

Tags: php

Well, very simple question. So that's good news for you, I guess.

More thorough explanation:

I have a PHP script allowing me to add urls to a database. I want the script to resolve the url to an IP address as well, to store that, too. However, some of the URLs are like this:

`http://111.111.111.111/~example/index.php`

So it also needs to work with that.

I'm not **SURE** that this is possible, but it only makes sense it would be.

So: Is it possible, and if so, how?

Comment: Yust one comment. Normal urls don't work with IP-addresses. For instance if you try to enter the ip of my server it would give you a 404 because you'dd have the wrong 'hostname'-hreader. Just thought I'dd let you know...

Comment: I don't get what you mean. Are you saying `http://111.111.111.111/~example/example.php` wouldn't work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[gethostbyname](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.gethostbyname.php)

```
echo gethostbyname('stackoverflow.com'); // 69.59.196.211
```

You can use [parse_url](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php) to grab the host from the url:

```
$urlParts = parse_url('http://111.111.111.111/~example/index.php'); 

print_r($urlParts);

/*
Array
(
    [scheme] => http
    [host] => 111.111.111.111
    [path] => /~example/index.php
)
*/
```

Comment: Thanks, this helped a lot. Especially the parse_url()

Answer (score 1):

[**gethostbyname()**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.gethostbyname.php)

```
$ip = gethostbyname('www.example.com');
```

It should be noted that if the website is on a shared hosting server, it is not guaranteed that your link will still be valid.

Answer (score 1):

**[gethostbynamel()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.gethostbynamel.php)** - Get a **list of IPv4 addresses** corresponding to a given Internet host name.

---

**Usage:**

```
$ips = gethostbynamel('stackoverflow.com');

/*
Array
(
    [0] => 69.59.196.211
)
*/
echo '<pre>';
print_r($ips);
echo '</pre>';
```

---

```
$ips = gethostbynamel('google.com');

/*
Array
(
    [0] => 74.125.39.105
    [1] => 74.125.39.106
    [2] => 74.125.39.147
    [3] => 74.125.39.99
    [4] => 74.125.39.103
    [5] => 74.125.39.104
)
*/
echo '<pre>';
print_r($ips);
echo '</pre>';
```

To get the host out of an URL you can use this one liner:

```
// 111.111.111.111
echo parse_url('http://111.111.111.111/~example/index.php', PHP_URL_HOST);
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, `gethostbyname`

http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.gethostbyname.php